# How do I find the difference in content between two Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have two Google Sheets. Both contain a column of email addresses.
One sheet is a subset of the other sheets.

I need to discover which email addresses in the superset sheet have been excluded from the subset sheet.

There is no other data in either sheet.

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: anything in [this reference](https://blog.coupler.io/linking-google-sheets/) which provides some clues?